# add nan if missing consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe like

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[1,4],[2,2],[2,1],[5,2],[5,3]],columns=['A','B'])

df2
Out[117]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  2
2  2  1
3  5  2
4  5  3
```

and I would like to add nan to the column B if consecutive values are missing in column A

the dataframe should become as

```
df2
Out[117]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  2
2  2  1
4  3  np.nan
5  4  np.nan
6  5  2
7  5  3
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a dataframe to append, concatenate, then sort:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,4],[2,2],[2,1],[5,2],[5,3]], columns=['A','B'])

# construct dataframe to append
arr = np.arange(df['A'].min(), df['A'].max() + 1)
arr = arr[~np.in1d(arr, df['A'].values)]
df_append = pd.DataFrame({'A': arr})

# concatenate and sort
res = pd.concat([df, df_append]).sort_values('A')

print(res)

   A    B
0  1  4.0
1  2  2.0
2  2  1.0
0  3  NaN
1  4  NaN
3  5  2.0
4  5  3.0
```